# How to add elements to a svelte writable store vector

Tags: svelte-store

I have this store:

```js
export const flights = writable<APIResponse>([])
```

And I want to add elements at the end of that array. I tried his:

```
flights.set({ ...flights, input })
```

But that doesn't add, it overwrites the existing elements, leaving only the one in input. How can I do that?

---

I am in a .ts. I'm taking over someone else's job who left the company and I'm new to all of this, I still don't have a clear idea of this mix of languages/frameworks.

When I print flights appears empty.
console.warn(`flights store:`  + JSON.stringify(flights))

{}

---

Some advances. It seems it was not empty. I wasn't printing it the correct way. I can see the elements added if I add them like this:

```
unconfirmed_flights.update((data) => {
     data.push(input))  
      return data
 })
```

and print the content like this:

```
unconfirmed_flights .update((data) => {
      console.warn(JSON.stringify(data))
      return data
 })
```

That prints something like: [{json_object}, {json_object}].

The thing is that in fact I have two stores:

```js
export const flights = writable<APIResponse>([])
export const unconfirmed_flights = writable<APIResponse>([])
```

The code receives several items that are added to unconfirmed_flights correctly. Then a dialog opens and if the user presses accept I need to copy the items in unconfirmed_flights to flights. I do that like this. First I create an index (id) with the empty array:

```
flights.update((data) => {
    data[id] = [] 
    return data
})
```

Then I add all the elements in unconfirmed_flights:

```
 unconfirmed_flights.update((uplan) => {
      flights.update((data) => {
          data[id].push(uplan)   
          return data
       })
       return uplan
  })
```

But the result, instead of
{"id": [{json_object}, {json_object}]}
is
{"id": [[{json_object}, {json_object}]]}

With that nested array. However, if I don't do the step of  data[id] = [], I get a "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.push is not a function", that I read is because the index does not exist. How can I avoid that nested array?

Comment: Have a look at [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/9a04b899e4364bb08b35f8e19a9133fc?version=3.49.0) to see that both ways you tried to add a value are basically working. Problem must be somewhere else... What's behind `<APIResponse>`?

Comment: export type APIResponse = { [key: string]: any } Yes, it added the elements but we had no idea how to avoid that nested array. But we found a solution. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
const flights = writable([])
```

If you want to add a value to a store from a `.js` file use [`.update()`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-writable) where the current value is available

```js
flights.update(value => [...value, newValue])
```

Inside a `.svelte` file the store variable can be [prefixed with `$` to access the value](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values) and the new value could be added like this

```js
$flights = [...$flights, newValue]
```

Comment: Hi. I edited the question adding the result of trying your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After three days of unsuccessful attemps to add the content exactly as I needed, I found the help of a JS expert. There it goes the solution.

Having

```
flights = {"1": { "name": "name1" } }
```

and

```
unconfirmed_flights = [ {"2": { "name": "name2" } }, {"3": { "name": "name3" } } ]
```

The goal was to add the unconfirmed_flights to flights:

```
flights = {"1": { "name": "name1" }, 
           "2": { "name": "name2" }, 
           "3": { "name": "name3" }  }
```

And that was done like this:

```
                    flights.update((plan) => {
                        const uplan = get(unconfirmed_flights)

                        uplan.forEach((uplanItem) => {
                            plan = { ...plan, ...uplanItem }
                        })
                        return plan
                    })
```

being

```
export type APIResponse = { [key: string]: any } 
export const flights = writable<APIResponse>([])
export const unconfirmed_flights = writable<APIResponse[]>([])
```

Comment: Great it's solved! I wonder why it's `const flights = writable<APIResponse>([])` if the response is an object, but the initial value an array?

Comment: Yes, you are true, it makes no sense. I pasted that from the code. I guess should be ({}). The former coder did that and I don't know why if later at some point it becomes an object. (Being new to Typescript, I am also surprised that you can redefine that).